# Select every group of two letter-\w after string

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

Here is the example string

> 00 00 00 12 A0 F5 CD 02 28 10

And the highlighted are the groups to match:
00 00 00 12 `A0` `F5` `CD` `02` `28` `10`

I tried with this

```
(?<=12.*)\w{2}
```

but it seems to be invalid.

Comment: So, you want to get `A0`, `F5`, etc. as separate matches after `12` value? What is the regex flavor? PCRE, .NET? `(?<=12.*)` infinite width lookbehind is only supported in .NET regex (and in 3 more engines I know).

Comment: This is Sublime Text 3 -text editor.
This is what I found " non-backtracking regex engine for syntax highlighting only" here: <https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/whats-sublimes-new-regex-engine/18944/2>

Comment: In Sublime S&R feature, you might use `(?:\G(?!\A)|\b12\b)\s*\K[A-Z0-9]+`.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Put it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\b12\b)\s*\K[A-Z0-9]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yKEHP8/1)

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\b12\b)` - match the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`)  or (`|`) a whole word `12` (`\b12\b`)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far
- `[A-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more uppercase letters or digits.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Must languages don't support variable length look behinds. If you want 6 bytes after `12` then you could do:

```
12 \K( ?[0-9A-F]{2}){6}
```

Example [here](http://rubular.com/r/4QP14Pu0y1).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand, but if you want to skip the first 12 characters, and match every \w\w after :

```
(^.{12})((?:(?:\w\w) ?)*)
```

Group 1 is the skipped characters.
Group 2 is the information you want.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/i7xi2P/1) is an example.

EDIT: My confusion came from the fact that `12` appeared after 12 characters.

Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/i7xi2P/3) work better ?

```
12 ?((?:(?:\w\w) ?)*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^.*12\K|\G(?!^)\s*\K\w{2}
```

You can try this.Ignore the first blank match.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/Y6VBgH/1

Answer (score 1):

`(?<!00)(?:\s)\K[A-Z0-9]{2}`

You can try this simple one also.

**Code:**

```
<?php

$string="00 00 00 12 A0 F5 CD 02 28 10";
preg_match_all('/(?<!00)(?:\s)\K[A-Z0-9]{2}/', $string,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A0
            [1] => F5
            [2] => CD
            [3] => 02
            [4] => 28
            [5] => 10
        )

)
```